# Удаление объекта в бесконечном цикле Tkinter

Tags: python, ооп, tkinter

У меня есть следующий код:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
class Example:
    var = 1
    def function(self):
        Example.var += 1
    print(Example.var)
    root.after(10,self.function)
Test = Example()
Test.function()
del Test
root.mainloop()
```

Когда я удаляю объект, переменная var продолжает выводиться. Я понимаю, что это из-за того, что root запускает бесконечный цикл. Как мне удалить объект полностью?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что у вас код доходит до del?

Comment: Так как появляется окно и в консоль выводится значение переменной var

Answer (score 1):

1. У вас `var` - атрибут `Example`, а не атрибут объекта `Test`. Объект-то вы удаляете, но класс остаётся, а `var` лежит в нём.
   (кстати, не стоит называть экземпляры класса именами с большой буквы, в питоне существуют чёткие рекомендации к именованию, которых стоит придерживаться)
2. Даже если сделать `var` атрибутом объекта, либо удалять вместе с объектом и класс, это не поможет - так как `var` используется в `function`, она не может удалиться окончательно, пока не удалится `function`. А та не может удалиться, пока существует `root`
3. А вообще - что вы пытаетесь сделать? Вы хотите удалить переменную, которая у вас продолжает использоваться в основном цикле `root`? Вам не кажется, что тут вы что-то странное делаете?
   Вообще, как показывает практика, в прикладном коде почти никогда нет потребности использовать `del`. Если вы начинаете явно удалять объекты, то в большинстве случаев это обозначает, что вам стоит пересмотреть саму структуру кода.

Answer (score 0):

Немного переписал код.

Необходимости ручного удаления действительно обычно нет, достаточно чтобы ссылки на объект достигли `0`, тогда тот будет удален сборщиком мусора. Например, тут `test = Example()` объект типа `Example` имеют 1 ссылку, в переменной `test`, а после `test = None` счетчик ссылок будет `0`.

Чтобы остановить тот цикл добавил поле объекта, чтобы индивидуально для каждого объекта можно было остановить.

Пример:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

class Example:
    var = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.is_run = True

    def function(self):
        Example.var += 1
        print(Example.var)
        if self.is_run:
            root.after(10, self.function)

test = Example()
test.function()
test.is_run = False
test = None

root.mainloop()
```